# How to implement $in operation in $filter aggregation in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, mongotemplate

I am trying to filter out the data in a nested array. My data is like below:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5836afca6dbd62de8d654h9"),
    "name" : "First Test Event",
    "registered_users" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5836e433e17ea92ea7a499a5"),
            "user_name" : "Malavika",            
            "user_state" : "registered"
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5836e433e17ea92ea7a455b5"),
            "user_name" : "Piyush",            
            "user_state" : "joined"
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("58369783e17e6e63c35f36ac"),
            "user_name" : "Jingi",
            "user_state" : "notified"
        }
    ]
},
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5836afca6dbd62de8d622b3"),
    "name" : "Test Event",
    "registered_users" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5836e433e17ea92ea7a499a5"),
            "user_name" : "Malavika",            
            "user_state" : "registered"
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5836e433e17ea92ea7a455b5"),
            "user_name" : "Piyush",            
            "user_state" : "left"
        },
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("58369783e17e6e63c35f36ac"),
            "user_name" : "Jingi",
            "user_state" : "notified"
        }
    ]
}
```

in the above collection I want to get only "registered_users" of first event "First Test Event" in two states "registered, joined".

My Intended result should be:

```
{
    "registered_users" : [ 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("5836e433e17ea92ea7a499a5"),
            "user_name" : "Malavika",
            "user_state" : "registered"
        }, 
        {
            "user_id" : ObjectId("58369783e17e6e63c35f36ac"),
            "user_name" : "Piyush",
            "user_state" : "joined"
        }
    ]
}
```

So I have prepared a query like below:

```
db.events.aggregate([   
{$match: {'registered_users.user_state': 'registered', "_id": ObjectId("5836afca6dbd62de8d654h9")}},
   {$project: {
        registered_users: {$filter: {
            input: '$registered_users',
            as: 'register',
            cond: {$eq: ['$$register.user_state', 'registered']}
        }},
        _id: 0,
        name: 0
    }}
])
```

The problem with the above query is instead of one state 'registered', I need an $in operator for multiple states 'registered', 'joined', 'left', etc....

Can anyone help me this?

Comment: Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/40701688/2683814

Comment: Hi I have already look at the $setIsSubset. But I am unable to pass multiple values to it like 'registered', 'joined', 'left', etc... In the solution that you pointed, I am using mongodb 3.2.7 and for that version I am unable to set the 'values ' variable. @Veeram

Comment: Try something like this `"cond": { "$setIsSubset": [ [ "$$register.user_state" ], ["registered", "joined" ] ] }`

Comment: Wow that worked awesome. Thanks for the help. Is there any possiblity that I can add a sort to this? like sort by "user_state" asc? And also please provide your $setIsSubset solution in answer. So that I can accept it.

Comment: *In the solution that you pointed, I am using mongodb 3.2.7 and for that version I am unable to set the 'values ' variable*. What do you mean? why can't you declare the variable like this: `let values = ["registered", "joined" ]` or `var values = ["registered", "joined" ]`? Also note @Veeram [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40819706/how-to-implement-in-operation-in-filter-aggregation-in-mongodb#comment68871023_40819706) that you found awesome is  exactly what the answer there is doing and even more. Last and not least if you have any other question, consider to ask a new question.